# If the user already complete the form only the submit button can click, and the submit button will link to another page

Tags: html

I want to create a form about the job application page, but i want to do some validation about if the user already fill up all the element in the form, only the submit button can click, and the submit button will link to another html page to show "your application is successful received". How can i do, thank you so much. I so a part of my code

```
<label for="Minimum Salary (MYR)"><img src="Web Page Image (Koh Xin Hao)/Money.png"/>&nbsp;&nbsp;Minimum Salary (MYR)</label>
<input type="text" id="Minimum Salary (MYR)" name="Minimum Salary (MYR)" value="RM "  maxlength="8" required="required">
<label for="Nationality"><img src="Web Page Image (Koh Xin Hao)/Card Issuing Country.png">&nbsp;&nbsp;Nationality</label>
<input type="text" id="Nationality" name="Nationality" placeholder="Malaysia" required="required">
<div><p>The application process will take up to 2 days. If your application is approved by the company, we will inform you via email or telephone call. Thanks for you application ^-^</p></div>
<input type="submit" required="required" class="btn" onclick="location.href='Payment Successful.html'"/>
<button type="submit" class="btn" onclick="location.href='Payment Successful.html'">Submit</button>
```

Seen the form is not fill up anything but the submit button also can click. I already put required="required" inside my code but the validation is not working.

Comment: you are going to need Javascript to validate your form in such a way that it will disable other buttons

Comment: @PaddyHallihan i already change it but still the same.

Comment: Is't every line of the input need to insert the same name?

Answer (score 0):

If i m not wrong so you want to ask that how to validate all fields and submit form to a new page.

**If yes so**

```
<input type="?" name="?" required />
```

add **required** attribute to require that feild

And give a action attribute to your form where u want to submit that form

```
Example <form action="your page" type="post">
```

Hope it helps you

Let me know if i misjudge your problem

Comment: Is it all the input need to add a same name as we put inside button there?

Comment: this is want i change base on your answer: <form action="Job Vacancy Successful.html" type="post">
<input type="submit" name="name" class="btn" onclick="location.href='Payment Successful.html'"/>

Comment: Is it correct? Because the validation still not working

Comment: As i reviewd you code you have give a onclick attribute to your button so now your form is not submitting But you told the browser to go that location so u just need to remove onclick

Because you have mentioned the loacation on your form action.

Comment: Thanks you, the problem already solved by adding my web page to go inside form action there, like you say just now, thanks you so much

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Javascript to check if the fields have been filled in and if so disable the button.

You also need to change the `required="required"` to just `required` as shown here https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp

You also need to wrap it all in a form tag and use the action field to supply the next page when it is submitted as per https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_form.asp

You may need to do more with validation in Javascript this is basicly only disabling the other button if the fields aren't blank. You can see more about JS validation here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

```js
function validateForm(){
  var input1 = document.getElementById("input1").value;
  var input2 = document.getElementById("input2").value;
  if(input1==""){
    console.log("input1 is blank!");
  }else if(input2==""){
    console.log("input2 is blank!");
  }else{
    console.log("inputs are not blank");
    document.getElementById("button").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="form_submitted_page" method="POST">
  <label for="input1">input1</label>
  <input type="text" id="input1" name="input1" required onchange="validateForm()">

  <label for="input2">input2</label>
  <input type="text" id="input2" name="input2" required onchange="validateForm()">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<button id="button" onclick="document.location.href='google.com'">Google (to be disabled)</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, my problem is already solve, thanks you so much